# INSERT INTO sqlsrv_query not working

Tags: sqlsrv

I'm trying to add records to a table with no success :( and even if the record is not added to the DB, it returns no error... I get "Ok" returned...

I know my connection is working cause when I change my query to FETCH info from that same table, it works.

```
public static function Test($pConn,$pNumEmploye,$pPrenom)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO [Test] ([NumEmploye],[Prenom]) VALUES(?,?)";

    $params = array('12','test');


    if(!sqlsrv_query($pConn,$query,$params))
    {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}
    else {return "ok";}
}
```

Please help before I go insane :)

Comment: BTW: Other thing saying it connects to the DB ok: My 1st argument is set as char(5) in my DB, and if I change it to '123456' in my query, then I get an error cause too long, but when in range, no errors, no entry

Answer (score 0):

Your code check doesn't check to see if the record has actually be imported into the database, that will only check if there is any errors, in your case there isn't any errors, so it will return false, and hence ok.

```
if(!sqlsrv_query($pConn,$query,$params))
{die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}
else {return "ok";}
```

Meaning you need to use something else, such as [sqlsrv_fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php) function, in your case [sqlsrv_rows_affected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296178(v=sql.105).aspx) will probably work.